# VSCode extension: disable repeating things in code completion

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a language extension for VSCode using Java and the LSP4J library. It is something like [this](https://github.com/adamvoss/vscode-languageserver-java-example).

But I have a problem - if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and the language server returns an empty list, VSCode will still offers its options - things that are already in the code. How can I get it to display something like "No suggestions" instead?

[image: I do not want this to happen (image)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text-based completion you're seeing there can be disabled with the `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions"` setting.

[image]

Extensions can change the default value of a setting for a particular language by [contributing `configurationDefaults`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configurationDefaults) in `package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
        "[lang]": {
            "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
        }
    }
}
```

Where `lang` is the ID of the language in question.

Answer (score 0):

If the language server sends back an empty list you could add an artificial entry with text: "No suggestions" to the completion list.